# Cmder opens in Windows mode half the time and xterm mode the other half

Tags: windows, windows-10, conemu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, cmder

I'm using Cmder with WSL and half the time, arrow keys don't work. I noticed that this is because Cmder tabs open in Windows mode half the time. Arrow keys work when it's in xterm mode, but not when its in Windows mode.

How can I force it to always be in xterm mode?

Edit: Also, sometimes AppKeys is off when I open a new tab. Is there a way to force it to stay on?

Comment: First of all you should use latest ConEmu build

Answer (score 1):

Add `-cur_console:p5` to the task you are launching (or you can use `new_console` instead of `cur_console`)

Excerpt from https://github.com/ConEmu/ConEmu.github.io/blob/master/en/NewConsole.md :

> p[N] - pty modes, N - bitmask: 1 - XTermKeys, 2 - BrPaste, 4 - AppCursorKeys; default is 5 (1+4)